# Android activity really slow

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

I wrote an activity with a text and an image. Both can change when the user click. It does change, but reaaally slowly. It needs around 2 seconds between my click and any change on the screen, when on the other part of the application, this delay is negligible.

Could someone tell me what I did wrong?

Here is the layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffc7c7c7"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:id="@+id/root">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/lockscreen_neutral"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Tuto"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:singleLine="false" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tuto_prev"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_prev"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tuto_next"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow_next"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

And the Java :

```
package com.gmail.jan4984.fl;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.androidannotations.annotations.AfterViews;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.Click;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;
import org.androidannotations.annotations.ViewById;

/**
 * Created by Nathanaël on 10/06/2015.
 */
@EActivity(R.layout.tutorial)
public class Tutorial extends Activity {
    public final String TAG = Tutorial.class.getSimpleName();

    @ViewById
    RelativeLayout Root;
    @ViewById
    ImageView Image;
    @ViewById
    TextView Text;
    @ViewById
    ImageView TutoPrev;
    @ViewById
    ImageView TutoNext;

    String[] tutoText;
    final int[] tutoImg = {R.drawable.lockscreen_neutral,  R.drawable.lockscreen_swipe_right, R.drawable.lockscreen_swipe_left, R.drawable.screen_home,R.drawable.screen_shop};
    int[] tutoTextBySlide;
    int slide,text;
    int screenWidth;
    //TranslateAnimation fadeOut, fadeIn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        screenWidth = dm.widthPixels;
    }

    @AfterViews
    public void initSlide(){
        Image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(tutoImg[0]));
        tutoText = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tutorial);
        tutoTextBySlide = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.tuto_text_by_slide);
        Text.setText(tutoText[0]);
        TutoPrev.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }


    @Click
    public void tuto_prev(){
        text--;
        setAnim();

    }
    @Click
    public void tuto_next(){
        text++;
        setAnim();

    }

    private void setAnim(){
        text = text < 0 ? 0 : text >= tutoTextBySlide[tutoTextBySlide.length-1]? text-1 : text;
        if(text == 0){
            TutoPrev.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            TutoNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else  if ( text+1 >= tutoTextBySlide[tutoTextBySlide.length-1]){
            TutoPrev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TutoNext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        else{
            TutoPrev.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TutoNext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        //CustomAnim anim = new CustomAnim(0,-screenWidth/2, Text, false);
        Text.setText(tutoText[text]);
        if(text >= tutoTextBySlide[slide]){
            slide++;
            Image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(tutoImg[slide]));
            //Image.startAnimation(anim);
        }

        Root.invalidate();
        //Text.startAnimation(anim);
    }
    /*
    private void endAnimation(View v, boolean fadeIn){
        if(v.equals(Text)){
            Text.setText(tutoText[text]);
        }
        else if(v.equals(Image))
            Image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(tutoImg[slide]));
        if(!fadeIn)
            v.startAnimation(new CustomAnim(screenWidth/2,0,v,true));
        else
            v.clearAnimation();

    }*/

    @Click
    public void root(){
        if(text == tutoTextBySlide[tutoTextBySlide.length-1]) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this,HomeActivity_.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
    /*
    private class CustomAnim extends TranslateAnimation{

        boolean isFadeIn;
        View view;
        public CustomAnim(int start, int end, View v, final boolean fadeIn){
            super(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,start,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,end,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,0);
            this.isFadeIn = fadeIn;
            view = v;

            super.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    endAnimation(view, isFadeIn);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {}
            });
            //super.setFillAfter(true);
            super.setDuration(200);
        }
/*
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float time, Transformation t) {
            super.applyTransformation(time, t);
            //view.setAlpha(isFadeIn ? time : 1-time);
        }

    }*/
}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: please add some device info or delete the question if you are talking about emulator

Comment: `tutoImg[slide]` what the resolutions of this images?

Comment: That was tested on my Samsung S5. No emulator. But i thinks the problem is the resolution (1.3Mo per image :S)

Comment: My guess is that it's because every time you hit next, you're loading tutoImg[slide] from resources. Assuming that image is a full sized image, that could be expensive. Do you have the same performance problems when not loading a new image? I might load the first image when the activity loads, and then load the rest into an `ArrayList` or similar with an `AsyncTask` while the user is reading the first slide.

Comment: 1.3 MB per image is quite large, even for a full sized Samsung S5 image. I would recommend you look into some optimization options, such as downsampling the images to the screen resolution. If they have a lot of solid colors (like text on a slide), encode them as .png and use a good compression service

Comment: Just downsizing each image from 1080x1920 to 300x588 make it considerably better. So it seems that was the problem.

Comment: @Selvin don't get me wrong...but why should the question be deleted if the emulator is in discussion? What's wrong with the question even if we are talking about an emulator?

Comment: Because emulator is slow, especially with graphics stuff, as was stated here on SO many times. As he wrote, he is using a good device so problem is not device...  Before knowing that there was no reason to analyze the code...